# CSS Styling list item back to default behavior

Tags: html, css, html-lists, items

I need my links to appear on top of each other like this:

> 1. First link
> 2. Second link
> 3. Third link

My links are appearing next to each other like this:

> First link Second link Third link.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

h2 {
    float: left;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: 500;
}

a {
    color: #15c;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

body {
 background: #fff;
 font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif; 
 color:#000;
 margin:0;
}

header {
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
    min-width: 980px;
    padding: 0 30px 0 15px;
    background-color: #fafafa;
}

header ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
}

header ul li {
    float: left;
    color: #8c8989;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

header ul li a {
    color: #8c8989;
}

.logo {
    float: left;
    width: 125px;
    height: 36px;
    margin: 12px 30px 0 0;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.add-product {
    color: #fff;
    width: 70px;
    height: 28px;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 14px;
    line-height: 28px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #EA4335;
}

.add-product:hover {
    background-color: #32ba55;
}

.add-product a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.add-product a:visited {
    color: #fff;
}

.search-box {
    float: left;
    width: 450px;
    height: 32px;
    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;
    margin-top: 12px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: none;
}

.inner-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
}

.side-panel {
    float: left;
    width: 188px;
    height: auto;
    background-color: red;
}

.side-panel ul {
    float: left;
}

.side-panel ul li {
    margin: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.side-panel ul li a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Google Project | Seller Central</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/seller-central.css">
</head>
    
<body>
    <header>
        <a href="?q=home">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        </a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                Hi, Guest
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="add-product"><a href="#">Add +</a></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="inner-header"></div>
    <div class="side-panel">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">My Products</a>
                <a href="#">Sold Items</a>
                <a href="#">Messages</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm working on the links located inside the div labeled "side-panel".

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/3p1j8cdx/)

That behaviour was because all the menu items were inside just one `<li>`. Split them into 3 `<li>`s and you'll get what you want..

See the updated HTML below

**HTML**

```
<header>
  <a href="?q=home">
    <div class="logo"></div>
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li>
      Hi, Guest
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="add-product"><a href="#">Add +</a></div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
<div class="inner-header"></div>
<div class="side-panel">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">My Products</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Sold Items</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Messages</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't believe it, I just realized what you did here. I inserted all my links inside one <li> tag. I feel really stupid right now.

Comment: Hahaha...silly mistakes is what makes coding this much interesting..Happy coding @RichardRodgers :)

Comment: could you please mark the answer as accepted if it really helped you..

Comment: @RichardRodgers: It should be noted that the bullet points are present there, and are just off the screen. Perhaps, you want them to display as you suggested in your question? Or if not, you may want to use CSS to hide the bullets. Some other details in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Use Instead

```
<ul style="list-style:none">
        <li><a href="#">My Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sold Items</a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

it will make it
Or if you dont want to use li then you can make`<a href="#" style="display:list-item"`>